# How to get vscode to recognise vitest globals?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vite, vitest

I am trying to get vitest globals api to work so I can write `describe`, `test` and `expect` functions without importing them in each test file like in `jest`.

I have managed to get tests passing by [following the guide](https://vitest.dev/config/#globals) but I am getting red errors lines when calling the vitest functions in vs-code.

E.g.

```
Cannot find name 'test'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner?
Try npm i --save-dev @types/jest or npm i --save-dev @types/mocha.
```

I'm sure this is a typescript configuration issue but I have added the global types to the tsconfig file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["vitest/globals"]
  }
}
```

What do I need to do to get vs-code to recognise the globals?

Comment: To my knowledge, you shouldn't neet to fiddle with the `types` field of tsconfig for a properly configured npm dependency.

Comment: It's working for me. Are you sure you've added that in your root `tsconfig.json`? Not something like `tsconfig.test.json`

Comment: Maybe `tsconfig.test.json` too, but for your IDE to understand, it has to be `tsconfig.json`

Comment: I had this. The answers below did not help but just restarting VSCode did

Answer (score 4):

Although adding `"vitest/globals"` to the `types` array is absolutely correct and even helped me resolve a very similar issue, you still have to restart VS Code's Typescript Compiler by running their built-in command:

`F1 -> TypeScript: Restart TS Server`.

This does not require you to install any additional npm packages, as vitest already contains everything you need.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your `include` option not includes your `*.spec.ts` files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This. Likewise check you don't have *.test.ts in the exclude key.

Comment: This is like solving a fire by turning off your fire alarm.  Yes, not applying typescript validations will fix the error ... but you'll lose Typescript validation on all your test files also :(

Answer (score 1):

If adding **"vitest/globals"** to types array doesn't fix this issue.

Then try checking the **include** option in tsconfig.json.

What to look for?

Ensure that you have listed the directory your test files are in.

For example, if your test files are in a folder named **"tests"**, then include **"tests"** as one of the array values of **include**.

Here is a example:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {},
  "include": ["src", "tests"]
}
```

This will tell typescript to include all the files from that folder during compile time.

Doing so fixed it for me.

You can read more about the include option here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include